# How to select all select2 elements, by pressing a button?

Tags: angular, jquery-select2

I am using the Select2 component of angular as a multiple selector. I need an option to select all the elements by clicking on a button or checkbox.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-select2

I tried inserting in the array [(ngModel)] = "value" all the id's of the elements when button is pushed, but it has not worked

.HTML CODE

```
<ng-select2 [data]="exampleData"
            [options]="options"
            [width]="200"
            [(ngModel)]="value"
            (valueChanged)="onTagChanged($event)">
</ng-select2>
<button (click)='selectAll()'>Select all</button>
```

.TS CODE

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.exampleData = [
      {
        id: '0',
        text: 'Pau Cano Dominguez',
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        text: 'Miguel Ángel Vargas Gomez'
      },
      { id: '3',
        text: 'Pedro Medina Cruz'
      },
      { id: '4',
        text: 'Oriol Fuentes Nuñez'
      },
      {
        id: '5',
        text: 'Rayan Mora Sanchez'
      }
    ];
    this.options = {
      width: '200',
      multiple: true,
      tags: false
    };
}
selectAll() {
    console.log('Select All Pushed');
    this.value.push('0');
    this.value.push('1');
    this.value.push('2');
    this.value.push('3');
    this.value.push('4');
}
```

Comment: can u put a demo code that you have tried on stackblitz.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ng-select2 component is using the OnPush change detection strategy.
What this means is that it will update itself only when it detects that its inputs has been updated.

You can see this in the ng-select2 [component code at line 31](https://github.com/tealpartners/ng-select2/blob/master/projects/ng-select2/src/lib/ng-select2.component.ts)

Now arrays are passed by reference which is why the component is not detecting any change. What you need to do is pass in a new array.
So in your *selectAll* function do this instead:

```
this.value = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']; // this passes a new array reference
```

To know more about Change Detection [here's a good read](https://blog.angularindepth.com/a-gentle-introduction-into-change-detection-in-angular-33f9ffff6f10)